# How to load a website with minimal internet speed?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I use Duolingo daily but sometimes my quota is over before the end of my internet subscription so I get throttled to 256kbps (kilobits not KBs) and this makes it nearly impossible to use the Duolingo website. Ideally I want to load the website with no styling (but keep javascript so that it can fetch the lessons) to be able to use it on my very slow internet. Also disable anything that consumes more speed that isn't necessary to just see the text body of the lessons.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Off topic, but have you tried theapp (for Android)

Comment: You can find extensions for each browser that block loading bandwidth-costly elements such as images for minimizing usage.

Comment: @davidgo I don't have a smartphone atm